# Is possible pass reference type to object instance which needs reference type dynamically?

Tags: java, jackson, serialization

For example:

```
public void builCarManager(Car car) {
   Manager<car.getClass()> carManager = new Manager<>();
}
```

Some suggestion to solve this?

**EDIT**

My main problem is in this :

```
public class CustomSerializer<T> extends StdSerializer<T> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(T car, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sp) {
        // I get car.getClass() fine but I need add it
        Manager<T> carManager = new Manager<>();
        // Manager<car.getClass()> carManager = new Manager<>();
    }
}
```

Here I can't pass `CustomSerializer<Lamborgini>.class`.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
private Lamborgini car;
```

Comment: You'll need to use reflection, but depending on exactly what you're asking for, even that might not be enough.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Comment: I edited my question...

Comment: What does `Manager` do? Why does it need a generic type? And why is `Car` not good enough for it?

Comment: Because Manager will manage a different type of car, I wanna know if the question based on my example can be solved with some work around... @Thilo

Comment: I think your `CustomSerializer` is not supposed to be generic, it should be a `LamborghiniSerializer extends StdSerializer<Lamborghini>`. Because it needs to know what methods to call on its input object.

Comment: `Manager` cannot manage different types of car differently based on its generic type, because that generic type is no longer present at runtime. When writing code to serialize an object to JSON you need to either know the exact type at compile-time or use reflection. In both cases, there are no generics involved.

Comment: @Thilo then you might help me how reflection can do that instead generic type?

Comment: What is wrong with the default Jackson serializers (configurable by annotations)? Those use reflection. Why do you need to make your own? And if you need to do, why not a dead-simple `LamborghiniSerializer extends StdSerializer<Lamborghini>`? And I still don't get what the `Manager` is doing during JSON serialization.

Comment: @Thilo this idea was because I will have a lot of cars then I can't create a lot of serializer as well... then the idea it is...

Comment: @nextsoft, May I ask why do you need class there? What you will do with it? Why do you want to custom serialiser for each type of class? Default configuration/serialiser does not work?

Comment: @nextsoft, please check my solution, maybe it help somehow to solve your problem.

Comment: @MichałZiober It's OK, I'm going to check it thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have below `POJO` model:

```
class Car {
}

class Lamborghini extends Car {
}

class Ferrari extends Car {
}
```

Your `Manager` class looks like below:

```
class Manager<T extends Car> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public Manager(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public String generateCustomCarName() {
        if (Lamborghini.class == clazz) {
            return "Lambooooo!";
        } else if (Ferrari.class == clazz) {
            return "Wild horse Ferrari!";
        }

        return "Not for everyone!";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Manager[clazz=%s]", clazz.getName());
    }
}
```

Now, let's create a `Store` which has one `Ferrari` and one `Lamborghini`:

```
class Store {

    private Car ferrari = new Ferrari();
    private Car lamborghini = new Lamborghini();

    public Car getFerrari() {
        return ferrari;
    }

    public void setFerrari(Car ferrari) {
        this.ferrari = ferrari;
    }

    public Car getLamborghini() {
        return lamborghini;
    }

    public void setLamborghini(Car lamborghini) {
        this.lamborghini = lamborghini;
    }
}
```

Now, we need to have a `class` information in runtime. Because of `Java`'s [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) we need to provide `class`:

```
class CustomCarSerializer<T extends Car> extends StdSerializer<T> {

    public CustomCarSerializer(Class<T> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException {
        Manager<T> manager = new Manager<>(_handledType);
        jgen.writeString(manager.generateCustomCarName());
    }
}
```

Notice that `StdSerializer` also has constructor which needs `class` and we can read it later using `_handledType`. Right now we need to configure our implementations with serialisers using `SimpleModule`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Cars {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule carsModule = new SimpleModule("CarsModule");
        carsModule.addSerializer(Lamborghini.class, new CustomCarSerializer<>(Lamborghini.class));
        carsModule.addSerializer(Ferrari.class, new CustomCarSerializer<>(Ferrari.class));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(carsModule);
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Store()));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "ferrari" : "Wild horse Ferrari!",
  "lamborghini" : "Lambooooo!"
}
```

Comment: nice! but how could I add it this CustomSerializer<>(Lamborghini.class) on annotation @JsonSerializer?

Comment: @nextsoft, you are not able to do that in that way. Only by creating `instance` of `CustomCarSerializer` together with `SimpleModule`. There is no other way.

Comment: @nextsoft, I'm glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to handle this is to have two classes (e.g. `Car` and `Desk`) implement a common interface (e.g. `Item`) and associate that interface with the `Manager` class.

```
public class Instance {
    private static interface Item {
        String getName();
    }

    private static class Car implements Item {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Car";
        }
    }

    private static class Desk implements Item {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Desk";
        }
    }

    private static class Manager<T extends Item> {
        private T item;

        public Manager(T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Manager[item=%s]", item.getName());
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Item> Manager<E> buildItemManager(E item) {
        return new Manager<E>(item);
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item car  = new Car(), desk = new Desk();

        Manager<Item> manager1 = buildItemManager(car);
        System.out.println(manager1);

        Manager<Item> manager2 = buildItemManager(desk);
        System.out.println(manager2);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Manager[item=Car]
Manager[item=Desk]
```

---

Another take... instantiating a `Manager` by passing in a class that represents an `Item`.

```
public class Instance {
    public static interface Item {
        String getName();
    }

    public static class Car implements Item {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Car";
        }
    }

    public static class Desk implements Item {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Desk";
        }
    }

    public static class Manager<T extends Item> {
        private T item;

        public Manager(T item) {
            this.item = item;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Manager[item=%s]", item.getName());
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Item> Manager<E> buildItemManager(Class<E> item) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return new Manager<E>(item.newInstance());
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            /* Cannot initialize array with generic types... */
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Manager<? extends Item>[] managers = new Manager[2];

            managers[0] = buildItemManager(Car.class);
            managers[1] = buildItemManager(Desk.class);

            for (Manager<?> manager : managers) {
                System.out.println(manager);
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you still get a `Manager<Item>` here (not a `Manager<Car>`) because that is the compile-time type. It is trivial to change it to get a `Manager<Car>` (by changing the type of the variable), but it still won't consider the runtime type. But this answer shows how the manager can keep a "witness" around to inspect the intended (runtime) type.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I edited my question, could you please help me?

Comment: @nextsoft I'll take another look, but I also covered instantiating a class at run-time using reflection.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  Awesome answer, please let me try it! thanks a lot if this solves  then I'll mark as asnwer

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Can you please take a look my edit? I wanna know if what I'm thinking it is possible..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use generics.

```
  public <T> void builCarManager(T car) {
    Manager<T> carManager = new Manager<>();
 }
```

Now you can pass any type of object. The created manager will be of the same type.

Comment: Yes, but I wanna pass it as I did the example